# Infinite digest loop in Ionic Apps after latest XCode update (iOS only)

Tags: angularjs, xcode, ionic-framework, xcode7

I have an Ionic app that I usually debug using Safari's javascript console attached to the iOS simulator. A few days ago, not sure exactly when, but I think it was around the time XCode pushed out their latest update, I started getting the following message in Safari's console output whenever I click a tab to change states:

```
Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: []
```

This causes the app to lag, and sometimes crash.  I reverted my code to earlier and earlier states with no resolution, so I tried creating an Ionic app from scratch:

```
ionic start throwaway
cd throwaway
ionic run ios
```

...and sure enough, the issue was still there.  I'm trying everything to no avail. Here's the output of `ionic info`:

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 5.2.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:  
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 1.6.4
Ionic App Lib Version: 0.3.8
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 4.1.1 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v0.12.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.0 Build version 7A220
```

The problem does not occur on Android, just iOS.

Thanks for your help!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer!  Apparently iOS9 breaks everything.  Luckily, Ionic's team saw this coming: http://blog.ionic.io/ios-9-potential-breaking-change/

Install the [referenced Angular patch](https://gist.github.com/IgorMinar/863acd413e3925bf282c) manually.  You can also update to Angular 1.4.6 as it includes the patch, but I couldn't find an easy way to do this on Ionic as it comes bundled with Angular 1.4.3.

Comment: I was having the same issue and installing the reference patch from Igor fixed it. Thank you